# updating values of retrieved object using the class method

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using class method (verify_refresh_token) I am getting token object from database, after which I call another method (generate_refresh_token) on retrieved token to update its values accordingly. However i get the following error:

> Instance <Token at 0x739447a8> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/bhk3)

```
class Account(Base):
    ...
   @staticmethod 
    def verify_refresh_token(refresh_token):
        with db_session() as session:
            token = session.scalars(select(Token).where(Token.refresh_token==refresh_token)).first()
       ....          
            #Update Refresh token if its going to expire soon in order to keep session running
            if (token.expiration - datetime.utcnow()) < timedelta(minutes=current_app.config["REFRESH_TOKEN_WINDOW_MINUTES"]):
                token.generate_refresh_token()
                session.add(token)
                session.commit()
        return token

class Token(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tokens"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    refresh_token : Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), nullable=False, index=True)
    expiration : Mapped[DateTime] = mapped_column(DateTime)
    account_id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"), nullable=True)
    account: Mapped["Account"] = relationship(back_populates="token")
            
    def generate_refresh_token(self):
        print("generating refresh key")
        self.refresh_token = secrets.token_urlsafe()
        self.expiration = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=current_app.config["REFRESH_TOKEN_MINUTES"])
```

how can i fix this issue and what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What line is causing the error ?  If you try to access token after `verify_refresh_token` it will probably fail because the session is out of scope.